# Jquery working only in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, browser, cross-browser

CSS:

```
.right_man
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;         
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        var page = $(document).width();
        if (page / 2 > e.pageX) {
            $('.right_man').width(page - e.pageX);
        }else {
            $('.right_man').width(page - (e.pageX - (page / 2)) - (page / 2));
        }
    });
});
```

Why code available only for Chrome ?

IE, Mozilla, Opera ignored hem.

I change changing $(this).mousemove to $(window).mousemove.

Fixt

Comment: create a functional example here (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can help you.

Comment: is it something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/bDgak/

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `$(this).mousemove` to `$(window).mousemove`.

Answer (score 0):

Try use [jquery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        var page = $(document).width();
        if (page / 2 > e.pageX) {
            $('.right_man').css("width", page - e.pageX);
        }else {
            $('.right_man').css("width", page - (e.pageX - (page / 2)) - (page / 2));
        }
    });
});
```

Let me know if problem still persists.